# What does "go by" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

> Meanwhile, Shi, who **goes by** Chris, shed more light about a confrontation Friday morning that he said led his family to contact  Redding Police.
>   [Source](https://www.redding.com/story/news/2018/05/27/two-chinese-flight-students-open-up-experience-iasco-staff/647842002/)

I looked it up means according to sth, follow sth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context "goes by" means "uses the name".

> Shi, who uses the name "Chris",...

You sometimes see a longer version "... goes by the name of ..."

Some people use an unoffical name. It may be a nickname, an alias, or they don't like their original name. Among some cultures it is common to have an offical passport name from one's native culture, and an unoffical "English" name which can be easily spoken by English people.

Later in the article it is written:

> “(McConkey) grabbed Chris’s arms and Chris tried to get away,” Yi said...

Yi is talking about the same person that is called "Shi" in the rest of article.